# Avoid changing table reference in view after renaming the main table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My table name 'Transaction'.

I renamed the table name as 'Transaction_backup' and I have created a new Table 'Transaction'.

When I renamed the old table, the table reference in view also changed into 'Transaction_backup'.

Here, I don't want to change the view reference. I found some answers from [Postgresql Rename Table without Updating View Definitions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87220/postgresql-rename-table-without-updating-view-definitions).

It's not possible to '**Create or Replace**' all the views.

Is there any other option to rename table without changing view reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql Rename Table without Updating View Definitions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87220/postgresql-rename-table-without-updating-view-definitions)